# Freeing components in a background thread in Delphi Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing an android app in delphi, where i dynamically create and populate Listviews. As the listviews can contain thousands of entries, freeing all the components can be time consuming, so to keep responsetime down, i want to do it in a background thread, but this causes access violations to occur.

```
        type

           TLVDirectory = record
             FListView: TListViewEx;
           ..
           end;

      var
        LVDir: TLVDirectory;
        LVDirectories: TList<TLVDirectory>;
        
      begin

        LVDir.FListView := TListViewEx.Create(Self);
        LVDir.FListView.Parent := Layout2;
        LVDir.FListView.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
        LVDirectories.Add(LVDir);
. 
     end;
```

Freeing

```
  LVDir := LVDirectories[LVDirectories.Count - 1];

  LVDirectories.Delete(LVDirectories.Count - 1);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure()
  begin

     LVDir.FListView.Parent := nil;
     LVDir.FListView.DisposeOf;

  end).Start;
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: BTW i use Delphi 10.4, so it's not ARC

Comment: Neither VCL nor Firemonkey are threadsafe, so you would need to use TThread.synchronize, which might defeat the object. Or not.

Comment: "How can I make this work?" You can't. Visual controls can only be used in the context of the main thread. If you have so many entries, you should use another approach and use controls that does not need to create thousands of visual controls, but only enough to present visible items. I am not sure if FireMonkey has such virtual list out of the box.

Comment: In the first line you set LVDir to LVDirectories[LVDirectories.Count - 1]; and in the second line you delete the entry. So what do you expect to be the value of LVDir after the second line?

Comment: Yet another *I ignored the large comment at the top of a new thread unit that tells you that you can't use GUI controls in a thread without using Synchronize* post. Sigh... Use `File->New->Other->Thread` to generate that unit, and then read the comment block at the top of it. Or the documentation for TThread, which says *Most methods that access an object and update a form must only be called from within the main thread or use a synchronization object such as TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.*